# Open a TabActivity with "simple" Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, tabactivity, android-tabactivity

I have a problem when I try to open a TabActivity with an intent from an Activity.

The code of my activity (ConnexionActivity), which is NOT an activity from a tab :

```
        buttonConnexion.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                     Intent intent = new Intent(ConnexionActivity.this, NeurokiffMobileActivity.class);
                     startActivity(intent);
            }           
        });
```

and the TabActivity (NeurokiffMobileActivity) :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    this.getIntent();

    /* ******** Gestion Onglets ******** */
    res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);  // The activity TabHost


    /* *** Onglet "Evènements" *** */
    /* Intent responsable de lancer l'activité depuis l'onglet */
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, EvenementActivity.class);
    bundleEnvoye.putString("id_user", idUser);
    intent.putExtras(bundleEnvoye);
    /* Crée un TabSpec et l'ajoute au TabHost */
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("evenement").setIndicator("Evenements",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_evenement))
                   .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    /* *** Onglet "Favoris" *** */
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, FavorisActivity.class);
    bundleEnvoye.putString("id_user", idUser);
    intent.putExtras(bundleEnvoye);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("favoris").setIndicator("Favoris",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_favoris))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    /* *** Onglet "Kiffs" *** */
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, KiffsActivity.class);
    bundleEnvoye.putString("id_user", idUser);
    intent.putExtras(bundleEnvoye);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("kiffs").setIndicator("Kiffs",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_kiffs))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

}
```

and the .xml of this TabActivity :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp" />
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="0"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

The error is a NullPointerException on the onCreate method of NeurokiffMobileActivity, and the application close. 
When I put another "simple" Activity instead of NeurokiffMobileActivity in the intent, it works.

Can someone help me, please ? It seems to be a problem due to TabActivity, but I don't know which...

Thanks in advance ! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the sample for you

showtab.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TabWidget>

    <FrameLayout  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" >

   </FrameLayout>

  </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Below is the code of AfterLoginTabActivity(a tabactivity to be called)

```
public class AfterLoginTabActivity extends TabActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.afterloginview);
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        TabHost tabHost =getTabHost();

        Intent i = new Intent(AfterLoginTabActivity.this,ProfileClass.class);
        TabSpec profileSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("profile").setIndicator("Profile").setContent(i);

        Intent j = new Intent(AfterLoginTabActivity.this,GroupClass.class);
        TabSpec groupSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("group").setIndicator("group").setContent(j);

        tabHost.addTab(profileSpec);
        tabHost.addTab(groupSpec);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);

    }
    }
```

Code i used inside my button.setOnClickListener

```
  if(msg == "success")
    {
        System.out.println("Inside button");
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AfterLoginTabActivity.class);
              startActivity(intent);
              finish(); 
          } catch (Exception e) {
               // TODO: handle exception
              System.out.print("tHIS IS EXCCEPTION" + e);
        }

    }
```

Comment: @djo i think ur '<TabWidget>' must be before '<FrameLayout>' in xml file and in ur class and u are using same 'spec' again to set contents.